# How to avoid using storyboards for ios apps?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6

I am learning iOS developpement (reading the Big Nerd Ranch Guide) and I want to learn using only my iPhone 5S as a test device. I am using Xcode 6.3.

However, as a beginner, I don't want to get involved with storyboards (which are besides seen as bad by some developers) and autolayout stuff. But, by default xcode does use that new feature and my windows are split when I run my sample apps on my iPhone.

How can I prevent it from doing so and use classic xib files for my iphone 5S?

Comment: I would recommend using "storyboards and autolayout stuff", why would you not want to? Because other say its bad? I say its good. Try both and judge for yourself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign your `UIViewController` subclass instance to window.rootViewController in AppDelegate and then take it from there.

Your project's Info.plist has a key "Main storyboard file base name". Remove that entry from the plist, and then delete the storyboard.

FWIW, storyboards aren't bad. In fact AutoLayout is much easier done in Storyboard than in code.

Comment: Storyboards are good, but have some limitations. Professional iOS developers should know how to use both.

Comment: @AaronBrager agreed, and pro iOS devs should know which option is better in which scenario.